# Mac OS X bash does not always add trailing slash for root directories

Tags: macos, bash

I'm using Terminal Version 2.2.3 (303.2).

The problem is when I try to change directory starting from root, I have to double tab for some directories to get trailing slash.

For example, I start to type

> `cd /et`<kbd>Tab</kbd>

it gives me:

> `/etc`

Then I have to hit tab once more to get needed trailing slash

> `/etc/`

And then, finally, I can <kbd>Tab</kbd> all further directories using single tab hit.

How can I fix this? I miss Ubuntu's bash so much.

Comment: Does `cd /etc` not work under OS/X ?

Comment: It does, but I need to access /etc/some/thing for example. And I am used to do it using less tab taps :)

Comment: Why not just start bash instead of terminal? Or `exec bash`. (optionally in some sort of .terminalrc)?

Comment: @Hennes Terminal is not a shell is a GUI application which uses the default shell

Comment: Terminal actually starts `/bin/bash`. Currently I ended up with changing it to `/bin/zsh` - which fulfills my requirement...

Comment: Feel free to post that as your own answer. Maybe add a screenshot like this http://cdn.osxdaily.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/03/change-shell-terminal.jpg   Or check out this on bash completion. http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Programmable-Completion-Builtins.html

Comment: Interesting. Usually, `mark-directories` is set to on in Bash, and should [do what you want](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Readline-Init-File-Syntax.html). See also: [Getting compgen to include slashes on directories when looking for files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12933362/getting-compgen-to-include-slashes-on-directories-when-looking-for-files)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is because, on OS X, `/etc` is a symbolic link:

```
$ l /etc
lrwxr-xr-x 1 root 11 2012-09-22 09:02 /etc -> private/etc/
```

that is, `/etc` **is** a file, not a directory.

If you try a real directory, like `/usr`, you'll see the expected behavior:

> `cd /us` <kbd>TAB</kbd>
>
> `cd /usr/`

You can force Bash to treat symlinked directories as directories with this command:

```
bind 'set mark-symlinked-directories on'
```

Add it to your `.bashrc` and source it (that is, read and execute commands from it) like this:

```
. ~/.bashrc
```

or reopen Terminal.

Comment: Ah, completely missed the symlink thing. Nice one!

Comment: Yes, that's very OS X specific. Another example is `/var`, it is symlinked to `private/var`.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, easiest way for me currently is to switch from `/bin/bash` to `bin/zsh` (Terminal Preferences - Shell open with).

Its a pity though, that I cannot easily achieve needed behavior with bash "from the box".

And I still have to export my aliases and so on...